# Making text/answer choices disappear/reappear in qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm working on experiment about distractions. As part of the experiment, I need a question to appear on the screen for two seconds, disappear for two seconds, then reappear. Here's my shot at programming this in javascript.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

    function togglequestion() { 
        if(this.getQuestionDisplayed()) {
             this.questionContainer.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
             this.questionContainer.style.display = 'block';
        }
     };

    var a1 = setTimeout(togglequestion, 2000);
    var a2 = setTimeout(togglequestion, 4000);

});
```

I think the problem is either in the way I'm declaring my function, or the if statement. I'm not very experienced with javascript so any bit of help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: the timeout function expects the delay in milliseconds, so try `setTimeout(togglequestion, 2000)`, also there's no need for a second timer

Comment: The current behavior is nothing happens. Which is why I believe the problem is either in the function declaration or the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument of the [`setTimeout` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is a duration in **milliseconds**. Currently, the functions is called two times *very* quickly.

```
var a1 = setTimeout(togglequestion, 2000);
var a2 = setTimeout(togglequestion, 4000);
```

Comment: Whoops, small mistake when I was copying it over. Changing the times does not make it work though.